# table rows collapse/expand css

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following example [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/) provided by PSL in a post on a website.

I have a large table and I don't want all of the rows to show when page loads just the headers.

Should I change the `border-collapse:collapse;` property in the css ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on dom ready you can hide the non header tr elements

```
$('.header').find('span').text('+')
$('table tr:not(.header)').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BsR56/)

Or using CSS

```
tr.header {
    cursor:pointer;
    display: table-row;
}
tr {
    display: none;
}
```

make sure that the default toggle is set to `<span>+</span>`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zb7h5/)