# Collapsing table with html

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I want to show used, available, and total for storage for specific servers. However, the servers have multiple drives and I want the default view to show totals for all storage for used, all for available, and all for total. But clicking the row drops it down to view the breakdown. I'll have all the data inputted into each cell, but I'm not sure how to do the drop down (collapse and expand).

eg. collapse view

```html
<table>
     <th></th><th>server 1</th><th>server 2</th>
     <tr><td>used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>available</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>total</td><td>2gb</td><td>4gb</td></tr>
    </table>
```

eg. expanded view

```html
  <table>
     <th></th><th>server 1</th><th>server 2</th>
     <tr><td>used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>drive 1</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>drive 2</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>available</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>drive 1</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>drive 2</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
     <tr><td>total</td><td>2gb</td><td>4gb</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [question][1] and the jsfiddle that it links to. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594817/table-rows-collapse-expand-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery so your new Jsfiddle(updated) : http://jsfiddle.net/5BRsy/3/

First set `class` and `id`s so you can call them with `JS` Note I had to do it for every `TD` because it wouldn't let me use div or span and hide them.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table2">
 <th></th><th>server 1</th><th>server 2</th>
 <tr><td class="btn">used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="expand1">drive 1</td><td class="expand1">0.5gb</td><td class="expand1">1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="expand1">drive 2</td><td class="expand1">0.5gb</td><td class="expand1">1gb</td></tr>

 <tr><td class="btn2">available</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="expand2">drive 1</td><td class="expand2">0.5gb</td><td class="expand2">1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="expand2">drive 2</td><td class="expand2">0.5gb</td><td class="expand2">1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>total</td><td>2gb</td><td>4gb</td></tr>
</table>
```

then use `JS`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".expand1").toggle();
  });
      $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $(".expand2").toggle();
  });
})
```

And `CSS` to hide them onload else they could see the hidden `TD`s

```
.expand1 { display: none;
}

.expand2 { display: none;
}
```

For more info visit http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: This would be great, but I forgot to mention that I want just the single category to expand upon, not everything. Meaning, if I click the row 'Used' - it expands just the used section. Not Available as well.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate your help. Can we not use an input button either, but just click the row?

Comment: Updated!If this is  the answer to you question mark it as solved(Just tick the answer)!

Comment: Works great! Is there anyway to use a -/+ next to the Used, Available to show expanded/collapsed?

Comment: Yea,sorry for the delayed reply here an updated JSFiddle : " http://jsfiddle.net/5BRsy/5/ "

So I removed the classes from the td's and added 2 span each td one for the plus image and one for the minus.In order for the image to appear change the "path to image" in the CSS to your images path and delete the "background color"
remember if you image is too big you can resize id by using .imagesclass { resize:both; width:14px;[ammount in pixels(example)]}
also i changed the Java hopefully you can understand them. :D

Answer (score -1):

A javascript function would be great for this. Just add classes to the rows that have drive 1/2 and ID's for each server and then you could do a .show and .hide if rows are clicked.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options. You can use this small jQuery plug-in: http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/

Or you can make use of Accordion from jQuery http://jqueryui.com/accordion/