# Adding +/- to collapse menu

Tags: html, css

Here's what I was able to get working with help from someone on here. However, I'd like to add it to include the -/+ when expanding/collapsing the rows.

[Collapsing table with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812997/collapsing-table-with-html/23813269?noredirect=1#comment36633967_23813269)

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5BRsy/3/

HTML

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table2">
<th></th><th>server 1</th><th>server 2</th>
<tr><td class="btn">used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
<tr><td class="expand1">drive 1</td><td class="expand1">0.5gb</td><td class="expand1">1gb</td></tr>
<tr><td class="expand1">drive 2</td><td class="expand1">0.5gb</td><td class="expand1">1gb</td></tr>

<tr><td class="btn2">available</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
<tr><td class="expand2">drive 1</td><td class="expand2">0.5gb</td><td class="expand2">1gb</td></tr>
<tr><td class="expand2">drive 2</td><td class="expand2">0.5gb</td><td      class="expand2">1gb</td></tr>
<tr><td>total</td><td>2gb</td><td>4gb</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.expand1 { display: none;
}

.expand2 { display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
     $(".expand1").toggle();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
     $(".expand2").toggle();
  });
})
```

Comment: post some of your tried code

Comment: So, what are you asking us?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to add the +/- element to switch between the two. The code is referenced in the link.

Comment: @user1052448: Post your code in *this* question.

Comment: Add an element that is clickable (like a `<div>`) with the text inside.  Then use Javascript/jQuery (whichever you prefer) to take care of changing the text between a +/- and collapsing/expanding your content.

Comment: So <div>+</div> and use JS to switch to - when expanded. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5BRsy/7/

Basically, you are adding some kind of html that you will use to represent your toggle.  In your case I used `<span>+</span>`.

```
<tr><td class="btn"><span>+</span> used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
```

Then, when you click the `<span>` (or the + sign I should say) you toggle the display of your content, as you were already doing, and then change your + to a -.  Clicking it again toggles it back to the way things were.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn span").click(function(){
        if($(".btn span").html() == "+") {
            $(".btn span").html("-");
        } else {
            $(".btn span").html("+");
        }
    $(".expand1").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the `+` and `-` you can try using `:before` pseudo-element, however it's just a trifle problem, the problem is your code, it's too messy indeed, I modified it much to make it more perfect. Fistly you don't need the classes `expand1` and `expand2` assigned to each `td` that way. You can take benefit of jQuery selectors to hide the rows initially and toggle the rows on click. Here is the modified code:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
 <th></th><th>server 1</th><th>server 2</th>
 <tr><td class="btn">used</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>drive 1</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>drive 2</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>

 <tr><td class="btn">available</td><td>1gb</td><td>2gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>drive 1</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>drive 2</td><td>0.5gb</td><td>1gb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>total</td><td>2gb</td><td>4gb</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**:

```
.btn:before {
  content:'+ ';
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.btn.expanded:before {
  content:'- ';
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**JS**:

```
//hide the rows initially
$('.btn').closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(td.btn)')
                   .not(':last-child').toggle();
//register click handler on ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(td.btn)')
                         .not(':last-child').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  });
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5BRsy/9/)

You can see that the code is much more concise and cleaner. Here is some related references:

1. [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
3. [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)